# String concatenation adds space when using a member of a Class that is not added when using a variable instead

Tags: powershell

I found a bit of PowerShell code from Microsoft using string concatenation like $variable".Name". I adapted this code to be used inside a method of a class and found a weird behavior, shown by this bit of code.

```
Class A
{
    [string]$a = "A"
    [void]Test()
    {
        $b = $this.a
        Write-Host $b"B"
        Write-Host $this.a"B"
    }
}

$c = [A]::new()
$c.Test()
```

The first expression returns a string with no spaces between A and B, the second one instead has a space between them.

```
AB
A B
```

I solved the issue by using "$($this.a)B", but I'm curious to know the reason for this difference.

Comment: i vaguely recall reading that the default `.ToString()` method pads the item with a space if the item is anything other than a simple object like a string. unfortunately, i can't recall where it read that. [*blush*]

Comment: Lee is right, `$b = [pscustomobject]@{A=$a}; Write-Host $b.A"B"` also has the padding, even after setting `$OFS` to `$null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of research, I think it's a combination of how PowerShell parses `$a"bbb"` vs `$b.a"bbb"` *and* the `ValueFromRemainingArguments` attribute property on the `-Output` parameter of `Write-Host`

Basically:

- `write-host $a"bbb"` is equivalent to `write-host "$($a)bbb"` which gets output as `aaabbb`.
- `write-host $b.a"bbb"` is equivalent to `write-host @( $b.a, "bbb" )` which gets output as `aaa bbb`.

**Long Version**

You can see the difference in how PowerShell parses the expressions if you inspect the Ast created for the following scriptblocks:

**Example 1**

```
$s1 = {
    $a = "aaa";
    write-host $a"bbb";
}
$s1.Ast.EndBlock.Statements[1].PipelineElements[0].CommandElements
```

gives this output:

```
StringConstantType : BareWord
Value              : write-host
StaticType         : System.String
Extent             : write-host
Parent             : write-host $a"bbb"

Value              : $abbb
StringConstantType : BareWord
NestedExpressions  : {$a}
StaticType         : System.String
Extent             : $a"bbb"
Parent             : write-host $a"bbb"
```

This is treating `write-host $a"bbb"` as equivalent to `write-host "$($a)bbb"` (see the `NestedExpressions`) and ends up writing `aaabbb` to the console if you invoke it.

**Example 2**

```
$s2 = {
    $b = [pscustomobject] @{ "a" = "aaa" };
    write-host $b.a"bbb";
}
$s2.Ast.EndBlock.Statements[1].PipelineElements[0].CommandElements
```

gives the output:

```
StringConstantType : BareWord
Value              : write-host
StaticType         : System.String
Extent             : write-host
Parent             : write-host $b.a"bbb"

Expression      : $b
Member          : a
Static          : False
NullConditional : False
StaticType      : System.Object
Extent          : $b.a
Parent          : write-host $b.a"bbb"

StringConstantType : DoubleQuoted
Value              : bbb
StaticType         : System.String
Extent             : "bbb"
Parent             : write-host $b.a"bbb"
```

which means `write-host $b.a"bbb"` is equivalent to `write-host $b.a "bbb"`, which outputs `aaa bbb`

**However**, we're not quite done...

**Get-Help Write-Host**

If you call `Get-Help Write-Host` you'll see output like this:

```
Write-Host [[-Object] <Object>] ...
```

but if we mirror that signature in a custom function:

```
function x
{
    param
    (
        [Object] $Object
    )
    write-host $Object.GetType().FullName
    write-host $Object
}

"Example 1"
x $a"bbb"

"Example 2"
x $b.a"bbb"
```

we get this output:

```
Example 1
System.String
aaabbb
Example 2
System.String
aaa
```

In the second example the `"bbb"` is being discarded in the function call because there's no parameter for this second value to be bound to, so there must be something else going on with `Write-Host` as well...

**Get-Help Write-Host -Full**

If we call `Get-Help Write-Host -Full` we'll see some additional information about the parameters to the cmdlet and it shows us the `-Output` parameter is decorated with the `FromRemainingArguments` property:

```
   -Object <Object>

        Required?                    false
        Position?                    0
        Accept pipeline input?       true (ByValue, FromRemainingArguments)
        Parameter set name           (All)
        Aliases                      Msg, Message
        Dynamic?                     false
        Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

So if we copy that in our own function we get this:

```
function x
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
        [Object] $Object
    )
    write-host $Object.GetType().FullName
    write-host $Object.Count
    write-host ($Object | fl * | out-string)
    write-host $Object
}
```

and now any unbound parameters get bundled into our `$Object`:

```
"Example 1"
x $aaa"bbb"
"Example 2"
x $a.b"bbb"
```

gives:

```
Example 1
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]
1
aaabbb
aaabbb

System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]
2
aaa
bbb
aaa bbb
```

We can see the first example passes a generic list containing a single string which `write-host` simply echoes out verbatim, whereas the second example any unbound values are bundled up into `-Output` which gives a list with two values in it, and the default serialisation for enumerable types in PowerShell joins the items with a space for a separator.

Comment: I'm astounded. Is there a book explaining PowerShell to this level of detail? I only find books for "non programmers" or cookbooks. I'd love to find the "k&r C language" equivalent for PowerShell.